Posicionar un button al inicio del contedor y un h3 centrado en el medio
Alguien me puede ayudar con este problema... Necesito que el button siempre este posicionado al inicio del contenedor y el texto centrado en el medio! Como puedo lograr esto?


<div style="display: flex;">
  <button type="button">X</button>
  <h3>Registrarse</h3>
</div>




¿Leíste la documentación de flex en CSS? Por lo menos en MDN...

Si lo vi inclusive no soy un junior en css, trabajo con mdbootstrap, pero siempre le doy mas al back y bueno estuve intentando y no lo consigo. No creo que este mal tener una duda o preguntar cuando no se sabe algo.

Por supuesto que no está mal. Lo ideal es exponer en la pregunta qué fue lo que ya has intentado.

Primero que todo, te recomiendo que mantengas tu css aparte del HTML para el uso de buenas practicas. Lo que quieres no es difícil de hacer, usa la propiedad de  justify-content: space-between; que alinea los elementos hijos de acuerdo a la dirección del contenedor. En este caso el botón al inicio y el texto en el centro. Después solo debes aplicar al texto una expansión del encabezado para ocupar el espacio disponible con flex-grow: 1;, alinearlo al centro y quitarle los margenes predeterminados.
Así quedaría tu código:


.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
<div class="container">
  <button type="button">X</button>
  <h3 class="title">Registrarse</h3>
</div>



